# No display on different kernel

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, cinnamon, multi-monitor

I got installed two kernels: `5.0.0-37` and `5.3.0-24`.

The first one runs smooth in my office - where I have three monitors and all of them are working, but when I boot it with no monitors connected - there is no GUI. I can access terminal though by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

The second one boots just fine with no monitors connected, but when I boot with two monitors connected - only the one in laptop is working.

I am running Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon on Lenovo Legion Y540 with Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti. I had to install some Nvidia drivers to get these monitors to work, as HDMI port is directly connected to GPU.

What can I do to run smoothing with or without external monitors on one kernel?

Comment: Have you checked that your NVIDIA driver is loaded

Comment: Right now on working 3 monitor setup it is loaded. Checked by `nvidia-smi`

Comment: what about when it doesn't work? That is the interesting part :)

Comment: Well, `nvidia-smi` says that driver is loaded when no display is working. Terminal is working fine. But no GUI